$S_n$ is generated by adjacent transpositions. Are there any other generating sets of length $n-1$ consisting only of transpositions?
$S_n$ is generated by adjacent transpositions. Are there any other generating sets of length $n-1$ consisting only of transpositions?
The motivation behind this question is that the set of adjacent transpositions $\{(12),(23)...,(n-1n)\}$ has shown nice properties in a problem I'm solving thanks to its size and the fact that the inverse of a transposition is the transposition itself. So I'm wondering if there are other similar generating sets.

@user14111, I suggest writing that as an answer, rather than as a comment, so we can upvote it, and so the question can be treated as answered.  We discourage answering questions in the comments.  We'd rather that you write it in the 'Your Answer', so it can be upvoted properly.  Thank you!

Hint: Define a graph with vertices $1,2,\ldots,n$ and  edges ${i,j}$ for transpositions $(i,j)$ in the generating set. If they generate $S_n$ then we have a connected graph with $n-1$ edges.
